# Use python slice objects when reading HDF5 file with h5py?

Tags: python, numpy, slice, h5py

I am trying to use python slice objects to access data from an HDF5 file using the `h5py` module. I put together this example to show that it works with `numpy` arrays, but not with `h5py`.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

slice_obj = [slice(None,3,None), slice(2,5,None)]

test_array = np.ones((3,5))
print test_array[0:3,2:5]
print test_array[slice_obj]

f = h5py.File("testing.hdf5","w")
f['data'] = test_array
f.close()

f = h5py.File("testing.hdf5","r")
test2 = f['data'][0:3,2:5]
print test2
test2 = f['data'][slice_obj]
print test2
f.close()
```

This gives the following output:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "slice.py", line 17, in <module>
    test2 = f['data'][slice_obj]
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 439, in __getitem__
    self.id.read(mspace, fspace, arr, mtype)
  File "h5d.pyx", line 179, in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.read (h5py/h5d.c:2479)
  File "_proxy.pyx", line 118, in h5py._proxy.dset_rw (h5py/_proxy.c:1300)
  File "_proxy.pyx", line 84, in h5py._proxy.H5PY_H5Dread (h5py/_proxy.c:1051)
IOError: can't read data (Dataset: Read failed)
```

Does anyone know if this is just not possible with `h5py`? If it is not, is there an alternative way to slice in `h5py`, using objects or variables, instead of explicitly typing the slice like `f['data'][0:3,2:5]` as in my example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Playing around with your example:

```
test2 = f['data']
print test2
print test2.shape
print test2[0:3,2:5]
print test2[slice(None,3,None),slice(2,5,None)]  # ok
print test2[slice_obj[0],slice_obj[1]]  # ok
print test2[tuple(slice_obj)]  # ok
print test2[[slice(None,3,None),slice(2,5,None)]]  # fail
print f['data'][tuple(slice_obj)] 3 ok
```

So it looks like `h5py` arrays can use slices, but cannot split a list into its elements. But it does take a tuple.  My guess is that there is minor difference in how `getitem` is implemented.

You are doing advanced indexing.  `numpy` doc says:

> Advanced indexing is triggered when the selection object, obj,... a tuple with at least one sequence object....
>   when the selection object is not a tuple, it will be referred to as if it had been promoted to a 1-tuple, which will be called the selection tuple.

`h5py` may not be doing this promoting to tuple.  Otherwise it appears to do advance indexing just fine.